# Would like <...> to expand to \text{...}

Tags: macros, expansion

Almost every subscript I write has to be in `\text{..}`, so to de-clutter, it would be nice to be able to write e.g. `x_<high>` instead of `x_\text{high}`.

(Shortening it to `\t{..}` is not quite as pretty.)

There was a [similar question about using  §...§ notation for this purpose](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/109992/15665), so the `\def` from the accepted answer there gives a half-way solution here. But the trouble is that I'll need `\lt` and `\gt` to map to `<` and `>` that would not be expanded in turn. I'm not sure what machinery to use here.

Comment: You could use a keyboard shortcut mapper instead.

Comment: @Azor-Ahai I use them heavily, but the lessons of markup and Markdown cannot be ignored...

Answer (score 13):

```
\makeatletter
\begingroup\lccode`~=`_\lowercase{\endgroup\def~}{\extendedsb}
\def\extendedsb{\@ifnextchar<\textsb\sb}
\def\textsb<#1>{\sb{\textnormal{#1}}}
\AtBeginDocument{\catcode`_=12 \mathcode`_="8000 }
\makeatother
```

Comment: This lets you use `<` and `>` normally, e.g., `\[ x_<high>>A_<op><B_<op> \]`.

Comment: If you want to be able to nest the `_<<symbols>>` then we can use `xparse`.

Answer (score 8):

It's pretty simple, actually. When you define some macro (or use `\let` to assign it) the current catcodes for the left hand side of the definition or assignment become fixed, so you can do the following:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\let\lt=<
\let\gt=>

{
\catcode`\<=\active
\gdef<#1>{{\text{#1}}}
}
\AtBeginDocument{%
\catcode`\<=\active
}

\begin{document}
\[
A_<op>\lt B_<op>
\]
\end{document}
```

The `\AtBeginDocument` part delays the actual catcode switching which can help with some packages that need the old category (for example for comparing numbers using `\ifnum`).

Comment: Neat! I guessed correctly that it doesn't allow nesting, but for some reason, if the nesting is through a macro, it works fine. For example, the following works: `\newcommand{\xhigh}{x_<high>} \[ x + y = z  <where $\xhigh = 0$ > \]`.

Comment: Or simply brace the index: `\[ x + y = z < where $x_{<high>} = 0$> \]`.

Comment: I've been using this heavily the last couple of months. It caused much less side-effect trouble than may be presumed. Such a simple fix, makes a lot of difference. One strange thing I noticed is that if we `\usepackage{mathtools}`, it stops working, unless we also `\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}`. An interesting case of package-package interference...

Comment: I've updated the answer mitigating somewhat the interference issue.